# Diferença entre URL FETCH e URL PUSH

Tags: git

Olá !

Consultando meu remote origin via comando

```
git remote show origin
```

Obtive o retorno:

```
  $ git remote show origin
  * remote origin
  Fetch URL: meu_user@177.xxx.xxx.xxx:/var/git/Projeto.git
  Push  URL: meu_user@177.xxx.xxx.xxx:/var/git/Projeto.git
```

Qual a razão desta distinção entre dois URLs (Fetch e Push) ? 
Esses dois URLs poderiam ser diferentes ? Se sim qual a utilidade prática disso ?

Comment: O fetch é relacionado a leitura, ex: baixar, enquanto o push é relacionado a escrita,ex:salvar alterações, os links poderiam ser sim diferentes(usando o comando `set-url` por exemplo) mas a documentação recomenda que sejam iguais. Utilidade prática? Sinceramente eu nunca vi, vou aguardar as respostas porque também fiquei curioso